# how to get Exit code=0 while killing a process using shell script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am killing multiple processes using "kill -9 pid" in a shell script and as expected the exit code is nonzero.

Is there any way to get exit code 0 while also killing the process using its pid?

Code snippet:

```
echo $1 $2
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "$1" | grep "$2" | grep "main-app" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); do
    kill -9 $pid 
    exit 0
done
```

Comment: Why do you want that? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: If you want a process to respond to a signal by exiting 0, then that process will need to handle the signal.  Since SIGKILL cannot be caught, you won't be able to do that with `kill -9`.  Clean up the receiving process so it handles SIGTERM and stop smashing it with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the exit code when a process is killed is unpredictable.

Bash takes care to set the exit code of a killed process to 128 + the signal it was killed by, so `kill -9` will always cause Bash to report exit code 137.

With `kill -9` in particular, the receiving process has absolutely no control over its exit code; it is simply killed immediately.

It is quite hard to argue that there would be any circumstances where a process should report success when it is forcibly interrupted, anyway.  Though of course, if you have control over the source code of the process, you can make it explicitly `exit 0` on some signals (though again, not for `kill -9` which cannot be handled).

Aside: You should *basically never* use `kill -9`. It is an emergency stop which should only be utilized in unusual situations (and even then you should know what you are doing).

As a further aside, you want to remove the [useless `grep`s](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) you have there.

```
for pid in $(ps -ef |
    awk -v first="$1" -v second="$2" -v app="main-app" '
        $0 ~ first && $0 ~ second && $0 ~ app && !/awk/ {print $2}')
do
    kill "$pid"
done
```

The `exit 0` you had in there would terminate the *current* shell (and of course, exit the loop).

Incidentally, the linked page also has a section about why to avoid `kill -9`.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple one-line solution works fine with all kinds of Linux/Unix. I tested it with Ubuntu, Mint, Centos, Amazon Linux, and Alpine (Docker).

This runs in a new shell and this way you can control properly the exit code.

```
/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/killall -q <process-name>; exit 0'
```